# Как правильно сделать выборку MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как правильно сделать выборку

```
select distinct location
from table1 
where (device_location like '2-%' or     
device_location like '3-%') and line_reg_no like '2%'
```

Типы данных: device_location - nvarchar, line_reg_no - bigint.
Отрабатывает с неправильной логикой.

Comment: Правильно было бы сделать line_reg_no строковым, если планируется такое его использование.

Comment: не, там значения int, просто по первой цифре понятно что это одно либо второе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct location from table1 where 
  (device_location like '2-%' or device_location like '3-%') and 
  CONVERT(varchar(30), line_reg_no) like '2%'
```

Comment: Можно объединить `like '2-%'` и `like '3-%'` в один `like '[23]-%'`.